Where are build settings in Xcode?
As the title says, how can I access build settings for my project in Xcode 15.4?
Here is the screenshot, so I hope someone can tell me what icon to click or tab to open. (I tried everything I think and googling it didn't help either.) Specifically, I would like to see which compiler version is set as default and possibly change it.


Click on the project in the left sidebar (with the blue icon).

The build settings can then be accessed from the tab bar at the top center of the screen.


I tried it before (and now again) and don't get any tabs. (Restart didn't help). All I can do is change the project name if I click once.

I created a new project and clicking on its name in left sidebar works. But it does not in my original project.

Perhaps your "original project" was incorrectly created.
